# Convert from dual-screen to dual-display

Tags: x11, xorg

I have a no name SBC similar to Raspberry Pi with 2 physical displays connected to it (one via HDMI and one via SPI). Below is my xorg config which gives me 2 separate X screens: :0.0 and :0.1

```
### HDMI

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "device0"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    Option      "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "monitor0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Modeline    "1920x1080_60.00"       172.80  1920  2040   2248  2576   1080   1081   1084  1118   -HSync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "screen0"
    Device      "device0"
    Monitor     "monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

### SPI

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "device1"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    Option      "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
    Option      "SwapbuffersWait" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "monitor1"
    Option      "Primary" "False"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "screen1"
    Monitor "monitor1"
    Device "device1"
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth 16
        Modes "320x240"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

### Layouts

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "multihead"
    Screen  0 "screen0"
    Screen  1 "screen1" rightof "screen0"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DefaultServerLayout" "multihead"
EndSection
```

What change would be required (if ever possible) in order to achieve 2 separate displays, :0 and :1 instead of separate screens? Can one make a ServerLayout which consists of displays, not screens?

Comment: I do not think that you can make a ServerLayout which consists of displays. Could you more clearly define the goal you are trying to achieve?